# GWT/Java app for Google App Engine: Have email address for the logged in user, how to get first name and last name?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I've not had much luck finding information about this and I'm hoping that someone can point me in the right direction.

I am building a GWT app hosted on App engine, to post a request to a remote server.  Very simple.  My form has a name field that I'd like to populate with the user's first name and last name.  All the users will be in our business's google apps domain.  I am successfully getting the user's email address by using the UserService as follows:

```java
public class LoginServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements LoginService {
 public LoginInfo login(String requestUri) {
        UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
        User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
        LoginInfo loginInfo = new LoginInfo();

        if (user != null) {
          loginInfo.setLoggedIn(true);
          loginInfo.setEmailAddress(user.getEmail());
          loginInfo.setNickname(user.getNickname());
        } else {
          loginInfo.setLoggedIn(false);
          }
        return loginInfo;
      }
}
```

Now, I need to somehow get the user's first name and last name potentially using the email address to look this up.

I've thought of the following ways:
- Can I use the google contacts API somehow?  I don't really want to look at an individual user's contacts, I'd like to look at the business's contacts which we are bringing in from Active Directory via Google Apps Direcory sync.
- Can I use Oauth to do this?  I haven't really been able to find good info on how to do this.
- Can I somehow get this from the Google Apps Engine UserService? (I think I've concluded that you can't do this - is that correct?)
- (Updated to add) I'm also looking into the provisioning API...I'm thinking this might work but don't want to overlook a better/easier way.

Any ideas, thoughts, or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OAuth 2.0 authentication as this allows your app to access users profile which include name. Look at OAuth client lib which [works on GAE](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Google_App_Engine_Applications).

You could also use [`scribe-up`](https://github.com/leleuj/scribe-up), which uses OAuth to get profiles from various providers, including Google.

OTOH, if you are only doing this for one (your own) domain, then you'd be better off with [Google Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount), which gives user-independent access to particular Google Apps account. This way you could [access profiles](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/profiles/) and get users data.

Comment: Google Apps Profiles API looks promising.  Thanks for pointing this out to me.  I'm going to see if I can get this working and I'll get back to you.

Comment: The problem I'm seeing with this is that the user must consent to the app using their user information.  Since the users of this app will all work for my company, I feel like it is an unnecessary step to ask for their consent to populate the form with their user name.  Is there no way to get this info without that step?

Comment: Yes, service accounts should be able to do this.